# Homotopy of a CW complex

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, cw-complexes

I have a CW complex constructed as follows:
[image]

(The circle and the rectangles are 2-cells, different 1-cells are denoted by different colors, and there is one 0-cell). We can see it as gluing two Klein bottles and a Projective space.

I'm trying to compute its homotopy groups.

The fundamental group is clear, but for higher homotopy groups I'm a bit stuck: If I'm trying to use a universal cover, I get a space equivalent to an uncountable wedge of 2-spheres, but as far as I know there's no method for calculating the homotopy groups of that.
The other tools I know deal with homotopy groups up to some degree, but that doesn't help me as I want to describe all of them.

Could anyone suggest a different approach, or let me know if I'm missing something in my original approach?
Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: $\mathbb RP^2$ has universal cover $S^2$, and so the two have the same higher homotopy groups. Since higher homotopy groups of spheres are generally hard to compute, I don't think it's realistic to expect to be able to do it for projective spaces.